# Should gui really be a tag synonym of ui?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I think [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) should be its own tag, because according to [What is the difference between GUI and UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191844/what-is-the-difference-between-gui-and-ui), 'UI can include non-graphical interfaces such as screen readers or command line interfaces which aren't considered GUI'.  So let's say I want to ask a question on [gui](/questions/tagged/gui), and when the user clicks on it in the question, it takes them to the [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) tag.  I don't want this to happen!  I want the user to be taken to a graphical world!  [gui](/questions/tagged/gui), my friends.  [gui](/questions/tagged/gui).

Let [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) be its own tag.  Who agrees, and why is [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) tag synonym of [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) anyways?

Here are some links where this change would be effective:

- [Is functional GUI programming possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672791/is-functional-gui-programming-possible)
- [C++ stylish GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345646/c-stylish-gui)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280380/python-gui-programming
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development
- [How do I build a GUI in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75863/what-are-the-best-resources-for-designing-user-interfaces

After research, I've noticed most (or all) user-interface questions are just about [gui](/questions/tagged/gui).  Should [user-interface](/questions/tagged/user-interface) be burniated, especially since it now has its own site?

Comment: Can you list 5 existing questions where this change will be effective?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672791/is-functional-gui-programming-possible also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280380/python-gui-programming and really http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345646/c-stylish-gui - if these are enough, this isn't my researching day

Comment: The first two are completely off topic as library request. The second one is even closed. The third one looks decent though. Fourth and fifth are also both definitely OT.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Here's two more to fit your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115495/is-python-any-good-for-gui-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c

Comment: Can you list any questions that would want to use [tag:user-interface] **but not** [tag:gui] ?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Sure thing

Comment: Looks like GUI should be a synonym for "lousy question"

Comment: There's a complication to this. ui is a synonym of user-interface (correctly I think). Removing the gui -> user-interface synonym without adding a gui -> graphical-interface tag would be inconsistent in terms of acronym expansion and related tags, however there isn't currently such a tag at all.

Comment: Create a straw-man `[graphical-user-interface]`, synonymize `[gui]` with *that*, then synonymize it with `[user-interface]`.  Then *close each and every question tagged with the lot*.